# Bulk save in Neo4j through Spring

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to insert approximately 100 relationships using for loop and Neo4jRepository's save method. However it is only saving last relationship object i.e. 100th object.

```
for(Book book:bookList)
    {
        System.out.println("saving: "+book.getName());
        bookService.save(book); //this only save last object
    }
```

BookRepository is as below:

```
public interface BookRespository extends Neo4jRepository<Book,Long>
```

I also tried to find out the saveAll method which is available in CRUDRepository but the same method is not available in Neo4jRepository.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I am able to save bulk relationships using cypher query(using spring data) but I am unable to find saveall method.

Comment: I am not sure what you `BookService` is doing but there is a `saveAll(Iterable)` method inside Spring Data Neo4j 5 Repositories. If you are using SDN 4 the method is called `save` and overloaded to also accept `Iterable` types.
You may also show the part of your service class to figure out what is going wrong.